# prism5 wpf View-Switching Navigation QuickStart demo doesn't run

Tags: wpf, prism-5

I'm new to PRISM, and downloaded the quickstart demos, and tried the View Switching Navigation.
i could build the solution, there is no error there, but when i try to run the application it gives error that cannot load CalendarModule.dll.

An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleTypeLoadingException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition.dll

Additional information: Failed to load type for module CalendarModule.

Error was: Could not load file or assembly 'ViewSwitchingNavigation.Calendar.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the path specified.

i've got this error at bootstrapper.run()

thanks for any hint!

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: i use vs2013 with .net45

Comment: I am able to run.. Check in the bin folder for ViewSwitchingNavigation.Calendar.dll

Comment: oops! downloaded in another machine now, and using vs2012 with .net45 it works now for me also. i'll check it with the other OS. the one where i have issue is Win8, which is working is Win7. anyway i come back.

Comment: ok, checked on Win81 machine. the module dll files are available in bin folder, but still have running time error. changed version back to .net45, same error. any thoughts?